# MongoDB: Bulk Upsert Throwing E11000: Duplicate Key Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am receiving "order" data via a websocket connection with some remote API.

For each update, I am getting deltas for one or more order items.

I am trying to save this data to Mongo using the BULK API, however I am getting an "E11000 duplicate key" error when using a BULK update/upsert.

The schema for the Order collection looks something like this:

```
var OrderSchema = new Schema({
    account: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account',
        index: true
    },    
    orderID: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        index: {unique: true}
    },
    clOrdID: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        index: {unique: true}
    },
    clOrdLinkID: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    transactTime: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        index: true
    },
});
```

I am trying to use the following code:

```
var _BULK = Order.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();


query = { 
    orderID: '1445d4bf-4813-6a75-79c9-b0341b116cde',
    account: 56e82fa332fca2200cb0506b 
}

// Received as delta from websocket connection.
changes = { 
    orderID: '1445d4bf-4813-6a75-79c9-b0341b116cde',
    clOrdID: '',
    clOrdLinkID: '',
    account: 56e82fa332fca2200cb0506b,
    transactTime: "2016-07-08T21:38:27.269Z",
    timestamp: "2016-07-08T21:38:27.269Z"
}

_BULK.find(query).upsert().updateOne({$set: changes});
```

When this executes, I end up with the following error:

```
WriteError({
    "code":11000,
    "index":0,
    "errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error index: testdb.orders.$orderID_1 dup key: { : \"1445d4bf-4813-6a75-79c9-b0341b116cde\" }",
    "op":{
        "q":{
            "orderID":"1445d4bf-4813-6a75-79c9-b0341b116cde",
            "account":"56e82fa332fca2200cb0506b"
        },
        "u":{
            "$set":{
                "orderID":"1445d4bf-4813-6a75-79c9-b0341b116cde",
                "clOrdID":"",
                "clOrdLinkID":"",
                "account":"56e82fa332fca2200cb0506b",
                "transactTime":"2016-07-08T21:38:27.269Z",
                "timestamp":"2016-07-08T21:38:27.269Z"
            }
        },
        "multi":false,
        "upsert":true
    }
})
```

Which to me would indicate there is already an order in the collection with a matched "orderID", which doesn't appear to be the case.

```
db.orders.find({orderID:"1445d4bf-4813-6a75-79c9-b0341b116cde"});
// or
db.orders.find({"orderID":"1445d4bf-4813-6a75-79c9-b0341b116cde"});
```

I get back no results...

**1) If a duplicate "orderID" existed, wouldn't this operation simply do an update on the item?**

**2) If a duplicate "orderID" does not exist (which it appears it doesn't), why would this throw a 'E11000 duplicate key error'?**

I have tried both ordered and unordered bulk operations.

**Update**

I also have tried using '$setOnInsert' to set the 'orderID' property,

```
 _BULK.find(query).upsert().updateOne({$set: changes, $setOnInsert: onInsert});
```

This throws the same duplicate key error. However, the bulk object's current batch looks like:

```
    _BULK.s.currentBatch: { 
        originalZeroIndex: 0,
        currentIndex: 0,
        originalIndexes: [ 0 ],
        batchType: 2,
        operations: [ 
            { 
                q: { 
                    orderID: '1445d4bf-4813-6a75-79c9-b0341b116cde',
                    account: 56e82fa332fca2200cb0506b 
                },
                u: { 
                    '$set': { 
                        clOrdID: '',
                        clOrdLinkID: '',
                        account: 56e82fa332fca2200cb0506b,
                        transactTime: Fri Jul 08 2016 16:38:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time),
                        timestamp: Fri Jul 08 2016 16:38:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) 
                    },
                    '$setOnInsert': { 
                        orderID: '1445d4bf-4813-6a75-79c9-b0341b116cde' 
                    } 
                },
                multi: false,
                upsert: true 
            } 
        ],
        size: 0,
        sizeBytes: 0 
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that orderID can't be set to the same value, because you are saying it should be unique. So you are setting orderID to an orderID that is already set. Why not just remove orderID from the data in $set ?

Comment: In the case of an upsert this field definition still needs to be set though?

Comment: Possibly this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14322